# Logic behind Insert into many to many database and cancellation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i am building a website and i have a little knowledge of php and sql.
I have many problems when it comes to many to many relationship in a database.

I have product that are specifical for every material e.g. there can't be the same product for 2 material

material are leather, simil-leather, cloth, PVC

field of use are the field which that material can be used: sport, leisure, work

The problem is that material can be used in many field and a field have associated many material, so it's N:M

a product can be used in many field and a field can be used for many product so it's too N:M

For example, leather can be used in work, sport, cloth in work sport and office

product can be used in some or all field of application and vice versa.

to achieve this is better architecture A or B?

(product have always the same application field  of materials, can't be a product belonging to a materials that has an application field materials doesn't have)

A) http://i60.tinypic.com/27zdk4k.jpg
B) http://i57.tinypic.com/2mhc03o.jpg

If i understand correctly, many to many relationship work with a "mid"table between the two.

So, when it comes to insert data and values in my database, what i have is:

MATERIAL

- 1 leather
- 2 cloth

MAtERIAL_APPL_FIELD

- 1 1
- 1 2
- 2 2

APPLICATION_FIELD

- 1 nautic
- 2 leisure

In this way, leather has 2 application field. But how i can fill the mid table in a smart way?

Also
When i want to cancel something, which is the better architecture?
and i should cancel from all table?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another good solution:

create table materials (material_id tinyiny unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, material varchar(60));

create table uses (use_id tinyiny unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, use varchar(60));

create table applications (application_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, material tinyint unsigned, use tinyint unsigned, active tinyint unsigned default = 1);

insert into applications (material, use) values (?,?);

The question marks would represent the ID of the material and the ID of the use.

It might be better not to actually delete rows from your table.  Instead you may wish to inactivate them.  Try this:

update applications set active = 0 where application_id = ?;

update applications set active = 0 where material = 1 and use = 2;

update applications set active = 0 where material = (select material_id from materials where material = 'leather') and use = (select use_id from uses where use = 'sport');

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, the solution below should work.  Keep in mind that their may be multiple correct solutions to your problem, and that I did not actually test this code so there may be typos.

create table applications (application_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, material enum('leather', 'semi-leather', 'cloth', 'PVC'), use enum('sport','leisure','work'));

insert into applications (material,use) values ('leather','work');

insert into applications (material,use) values ('leather','leisure');

Comment: I was just trying to help.  Perhaps you could clarify your question next time before automatically down voting my response.

Comment: OK.  Sorry about the assumption.